# How can i include the android code developed on linux platform into the eclipse

Tags: android

How can i include the android code developed on linux platform into the eclipse on windows platform so that i can debug and start the emulator which will emulate same as target behaviour.
To be further precise this android code is having application as well as JNI and c/c++ code

Answer (score 0):

Just copy the whole project folder to windows, and import the project into Eclipse. Then create a emulator which is as same as the one on Linux platform. After that, You can run or debug your app on the emulator without any problem.